# Attaching a legend to BallAndStick picture

Tags: graphics3d, legending, chemistry

I am looking for a way to add a legend showing the identity of various atoms (with different colours) to this picture. Any Clues?

```
Import["ExampleData/1PPT.pdb", "Rendering" -> "BallAndStick"]
```

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
bas = Import["ExampleData/1PPT.pdb", "Rendering" -> "BallAndStick", 
   ImageSize -> 500];

elements = 
  Import["ExampleData/1PPT.pdb", "ResidueAtoms"] // Flatten // Union;

legend = GraphicsColumn[{
    {Graphics[{#[[1]], Disk[{0, 0}, 1]}, ImageSize -> 10], #[[2]]} & /@
     Thread[{
       ElementData[#, "IconColor"] & /@ elements,
       ElementData[#, "StandardName"] & /@ elements}]}];

Row[{bas, legend}]
```

[image]

Alternative legend:

```
legend = GraphicsColumn[
   Row[{Graphics[{#[[1]], Disk[{0, 0}, 1]}, ImageSize -> 10], 
       " " <> #[[2]]}] & /@ 
    Thread[{ElementData[#, "IconColor"] & /@ elements, 
      ElementData[#, "StandardName"] & /@ elements}], 
   ImageSize -> 100];

Row[{bas, legend}]
```

[image]

Comment: +1 and thanks. Would you try to remove the distracting brackets around the legend?

Answer (score 18):

Bob Hanlon's [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/59587/52) works very well, but in some ways it is the hard way of doing things. If you have v9 or v10, then it is arguably easier to use the legend constructs within it. Similar to his answer, we get the image and element names:

```
img = Import["ExampleData/1PPT.pdb", "Rendering" -> "BallAndStick", ImageSize -> 500];
elements = Import["ExampleData/1PPT.pdb", "ResidueAtoms"] // Flatten // Union;
```

But, we deviate with the legend construction, e.g.

```
legend = SwatchLegend[
  ElementData[#, "IconColor"] & /@ elements, 
  ElementData[#, "StandardName"] & /@ elements, 
  LegendMarkers -> Graphics@Disk[]
]
```

and to display the legend, we use

```
Legended[img, legend]
```

[image]

At this point, there is not much in the way of savings, but it simplifies a number of things, such as repositioning the legend using `Placed`, or adding additional legends. For instance, what if the pdb file also displayed hydrogen bonds, in addition to covalent bonds, then it is straightforward to add a second legend:

```
legendRow = SwatchLegend[
  ElementData[#, "IconColor"] & /@ elements, 
  ElementData[#, "StandardName"] & /@ elements, 
  LegendMarkers -> Graphics@Disk[],
  LegendLayout -> "Row"
];
legendBonds = LineLegend[
  {Gray, Directive[Red, Dashed]}, 
  {"Covalent", "Hydrogen"}
];

Legended[img, {Placed[legendRow, Top], legendBonds}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

To show the colors associated with atoms, use the `Automatic` setting for the PlotLegends option:

```
MoleculePlot3D[
    Molecule @ "1-(amino-dimethyl-silyl)-2,3,4,5,6-pentafluoro-benzene", 
    PlotLegends -> Automatic
]
```

[image]

The example in the OP does not work yet, but the PDB importer will be updated in a future release.